# How to read .blg file

Tags: windows, performance, perfmon

How to open a blg file generated by perfmon.exe. When I open the blg file, it will open Performance and start monitoring the current activity.

Answer (score 4):

The perfmon logs or data in BLG file will only capture counters you specify
while creating the counter logs.

To open the blg file, follow steps below
1) Click start>>run
2) Type perfmon and press enter
3) In system monitor select and remove the counters currently shown by
hitting the delete button
4) Click the fourth button that says "View log data" this button has a
cylinder icon
5) Point and open the blg file.
6) To view the log you can click the + sign button which is the 8th button
on the top. add the counters and objects that you want to view.
7) You can also adjust the graph scale by right clicking inside the graph.
8) To highlight a particular counter line, select the bulb icon on the top
and click on a counter or a line in the graph.

[Reference](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/read-performance-log-file-blg-t3787294.html)